# Unpublish G Suite Marketplace add-on

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have published my Google Spreadsheets add-on to the Chrome Web Store and in addition to the G Suite Marketplace.
I have done this via the script editor, where I clicked Publish > Deploy as Google Sheets add-on.

It worked, the add-on is now live in both stores.

Unfortunately I would like to unpublish it for some time.
I can do this within the Chrome Web Store dashboard. I have chosen the "not listed option". This way I can send the link to test users.

But these changes seem not to be synced to the G Suite Marketplace. Because in there I can still find the add-on.
And the "unpublish button" within the G Suite Marketplace / Publish panel is frozen.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a similar problem - I created a bundled version (for more than one editor) of an add-on, which required defining a new project. The legacy version (non-bundled, for just one editor) is showing along with the new one, and the "Unpublish" button is grayed out in GSM screen for the old project. Can you confirm that Google handled your issue (per the accepted answer)?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: Yes I can confirm, my issue was handled by Google as explained in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the migration from CWS to GSM is finished, there's a process that syncs CWS add-ons with the GSM ones. This process takes about two days.

If after waiting the add-on is still published in GSM, please create an issue in
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191597 and provide the cloud project number (the GSM app ID).